# How to structure in handling websocket and inserting data to databse in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, websocket

I connected to the websocket, and the data response in the callback function `handle_message`. I wish to insert all the data to influxdb using `write_api.write()`, since I need `with InfluxClient()` to wrap the whole CRUD function, I wrote like this:

```
from time import sleep
from pybit import usdt_perpetual
from dataclasses import dataclass
from influxdb_client import InfluxDBClient
from influxdb_client.client.write_api import SYNCHRONOUS


@dataclass
class Trade:
    tick_direction: str
    side: float
    is_block_trade: str
    price: float
    size: float
    timestamp: int


ws_linear = usdt_perpetual.WebSocket(
    test=False,
    ping_interval=30, 
    ping_timeout=10, 
    domain="bybit"  
)

with InfluxDBClient(
        url="http://localhost:8086",
        token="fake_token_id",
        org="organization") as client:
    write_api = client.write_api(write_options=SYNCHRONOUS)


    def handle_message(msg: dict) -> None:
        for data in msg["data"]:
            trade = Trade(data["tick_direction"], data["side"], data["is_block_trade"], float(data["price"]),
                          float(data["size"]), data["timestamp"])
            write_api.write(bucket="test5",
                            record=trade,
                            record_measurement_name="tradeBTCUSDT",
                            record_time_key="timestamp",
                            record_tag_keys=["tick_direction", "side", "is_block_trade"],
                            record_field_keys=["price", "size"])

ws_linear.trade_stream(
    handle_message, "BTCUSDT"
)

while True:
    sleep(1)
```

I think it is messy that I wrap `handle_message` by `with InfluxClient`, how can I improve it and the overall structure of the program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find it unlikely this program works as expected.  You have written approximately:

1. Open a database connection, & assign that to `client`
2. Get `write_api` from `client`
3. Define a function which (at some point in the future) uses `write_api`
4. Call `client.close()` **due to the exit of the `with` statement!**
5. Ask another function to handle messages by calling your defined function which uses an api **on a “now closed” `client`!**

As you can see, the `with` statement is not doing anything but giving you a false sense of security.  You need to either:

- open a new database connection inside `handle_message`, or
- indent the subsequent code such that `client` is not closed until after your `while True:` loop exits (presumably by a `KeyboardInterrupt`)

---

Here is a toy demonstration of the issue:

```
class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.opened = False
        
    def __enter__(self):
        self.opened = True
        print("Client opened")
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.opened = False
        print("Client closed")

    def write_api(self):
        return WriteApi(self)

class WriteApi():
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    def use_api(self):
        print("Using API.  Client open =", self.client.opened)

def trade_stream(handler):
    handler(None)


print("About to enter with-statement")
with Client() as client:
    print("Entered with-statement")
    write_api = client.write_api()
    
    def handle_message(msg):
        write_api.use_api()

    print("Exiting with-statement")

print("Exited with-statement")


trade_stream(handle_message)
```

Output:

```
About to enter with-statement
Client opened
Entered with-statement
Exiting with-statement
Client closed
Exited with-statement
Using API.  Client open = False
```

Note that using the API happens after the client has been closed.

---

So why do you appear to have working code?

From the [documentation](https://influxdb-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#influxdb_client.InfluxDBClient.write_api) ...

```
from influxdb_client import InfluxDBClient

# Initialize background batching instance of WriteApi
with InfluxDBClient(url="http://localhost:8086", token="my-token", org="my-org") as client:
    with client.write_api() as write_api:
        pass
```

... it appears `client.write_api()` returns an object which itself can behave as a context manager, and so should be used in a with-statement.

If the `write_api` is "open", and then the `client` is closed, whether or not the `write_api` is invalid will depend on how the library is written.  It may internally hold the `client` open, until the `write_api` is explicitly closed (which you are not doing), or it may be *Undefined Behaviour* and might appear to work at the moment, and start failing in the future.

---

As stated earlier, the fix could be to indent the subsequent code, as in:

```
with InfluxDBClient(
        url="http://localhost:8086",
        token="fake_token_id",
        org="organization") as client:
    write_api = client.write_api(write_options=SYNCHRONOUS)


    def handle_message(msg: dict) -> None:
        ...


    # still indented, so still inside the `with client`

    ws_linear.trade_stream(
        handle_message, "BTCUSDT"
    )

    # still indented, so still inside the `with client`

    while True:
        sleep(1)

    # with statement ends here

# client will be closed here
```